# Getting 'weird' RSS results in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

I'm not sure if this is a good question, but I'm really blocked by this. Need some advice.

I'm working on an Android app where a part of the app is to retrieve 2 seperate RSS feeds in 2 different menus.

I'm using the same code for both feeds, but both feeds come up 'weird'.

Some urls I use come up fine, with titles all lined up well, while other urls I use, like the ones I need (one is from ReverbNation (show schedule) and one is from Facebook (wall feed)), end up getting shown all 'split up'.

What happens is that when I put the results in a ListView, and I see the results back, some strings have been split up into seperate strings / listview items and some strings are even blank and show up as blank listview items.

Is there any advice someone has for me? I know it's kind of a vague question, but I hit a wall here.

Code:

```
private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler
   {
        final int stateUnknown = 0;
        final int stateTitle = 1;
        final int stateLink = 2;
        int state = stateUnknown;

          @Override
          public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          }

          @Override
          public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          }

          @Override
          public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            localnames.add(localName);

           if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
           {
               state = stateTitle;
           } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
               state = stateLink;
           } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
               Log.d("Tour", "item");
           }
           else
           {
               state = stateUnknown;
           }
      }

      @Override
      public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       state = stateUnknown;
      }

      @Override
      public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       String strCharacters = new String(ch, start, length);

       xmlStrings.add(strCharacters);

       if (state == stateTitle)
       {
           item.add(strCharacters);

       } else if (state == stateLink)
       {
           itemLink.add(strCharacters);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Seems like SAX is the problem? Still looking into this.. But might it be the solution to switch over to DOM parsing?

Comment: I have always used JDOM for XML parsing and now it officially supports android: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-and-Android